# Using Derivative to get $(x,y)$ value

Tags: calculus

How do you use a derivative to find a point? For instance, how would you extract the $(x,y)$ values from:

$p'(0) = 0$

and

$p'(-1) = -1$

Comment: Your question is weird...to say the least: **what** point $\;(x,y\;$) are you looking for? On the function's graph, on the function's derivative's graph...?? What is $\;p\;$, besides obviously a function defined and differentiable on $\;x=-1,0\;$ ?

Comment: We are learning Newton's interpolating polynomials and Lagrange's interpolating polynomials. The exact question I am trying to solve is:

Find a polynomial, p(x), of degree no more than 3 such that the following hold:
p(0) = 1, p(1) = 0, p'(0) = 0, p'(-1) = -1

So two points are given, but I don't see how to get the points to use from the derivatives. I need four points total to use either of these formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: it is given that

$$p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\implies\begin{cases}1=p(0)=d\\{}\\0=p(1)=a+b+c+d\\{}\\0=p'(0)=c\\{}\\-1=p'(-1)=3a-2b+c\end{cases}$$

Well, solve the above linear system for $\;a,b,c,d\;$ and you're done...

Comment: Writing it out in that format is very helpful. I understand what is being asked much better now.